# IDA - Create Process Flow Map Between 2 Sub-Routines

Tags: ida

Using IDA, can I specify 2 Sub-Routines (really, it's 2 WINAPI calls) and have IDA create a "map" between the 2 points? I want to know all the possible branches the EIP can take from one instruction to another instruction.

I am using IDA-Pro 6.0 (or 6.1).

Thank you.

Edit - I can only use static analysis tools for this.

Comment: see https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1590/60

Comment: Thank you for such a fast reply. I will look at this. I edited my question just now to include a detail about require a static analysis solution.

Comment: Do you want to find a path between two functions ?

Comment: That is correct, @0xec

Comment: The solution in the post I linked to does not rely on dynamic analysis BTW.

Comment: Thank you, Igor. I wanted to make the question more specific to avoid answers involving Traces. Is your solution viable with the specified version of IDA, perhaps as a plugin? I see that feature is packaged with 6.2+ versions.

Comment: IDA 6.0/6.1 is pretty-pretty old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [alleycat](https://github.com/devttys0/ida/tree/master/plugins/alleycat) plugin to find the path between two functions/basic blocks etc.

### Example

Finding the path between two functions `http_init_main` and `http_parser_set_challenge` in a mipsel elf.

1. Go to View -> Find paths from current function to...

   [image]
2. Select the target function.

   [image]
3. Alleycat would display the path to reach the selected function from initial function. Additionally, the corresponding basic blocks would be highlighted in the graph view.

   [image]