# idapython - Scan all possible code paths between start and end addresses

Tags: ida, malware, idapython

I have a start and end address inside a function segment. How can I step through all the possible code paths easily, including jumps, function calls, etc that occur between the start and the end point?

I am trying to find a particular condition that I know occurs somewhere deep in the function segment. (I know how to do this part)

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/16769/1413

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm after but the source could be helpful. Thanks.